# need a repeatable method for SSIS package OnError Event Handler

Tags: event-handling, ssis-2012, modularity, onerror

All the SSIS packages here at work have an identical OnError event handler and I'm looking for a way to avoid creating the same handler for every single package.  The Event Handler first queries a table for a list of email addresses and then sends an email to the list of recipients, including in the body the package name, package error, error date & time, etc.  The Execute SQL query and Email Task are literally identical in every package Event Handler.  Is there some way to modularize this routine?  Perhaps by calling another package that handles it all?  I want to eliminate (or nearly eliminate) chances for developers to make a mistake while creating, recreating, and recreating yet again this identical process.  They way it's done now will be a miserable task to make a simple change to our error handling process in all our packages.

Answer (score 0):

After extensive searching, I think I've settled on my best options: a custom SSIS task, a child package, or a stored procedure (in an Execute SQL task).  I don't know how to make a custom task, so I'm going to opt for the child package and pass various execution state variables (like error description, error number, package name, package start time, etc.) into the child package as parameters.  I assume I could make a custom task that only needs to be dropped into the error handler to work properly, but I don't have time to learn how.